# What kind of component needed for this purpose?

Tags: components

I need to precisely manually adjust R4 and R5 to the same value below using only one potentiometer or something similar(these resistors set the gain):

[image]

I mean if I manually adjust the knob both resistor should go to the same value. Of course they should be isolated from each other as you see they are at different part of the circuit. Is there such a components or potentiometer?

Comment: There are dual potentiometers, just checked. But the value cannot be guaranteed to be *exactly* the same.

Comment: Can you improve the title of your question please to be more descriptive, at the moment it's little better than 'need help'. Something like 'how do I track two resistors to set amplifier gain'. Do you only need to match them, in which can only one needs to be adjustable. or must they both take a range of values?

Comment: Does it need to be continuously variable? If not, you could make/buy a dual (stereo) stepped attenuator.

Answer (score 1):

Dual gang potentiometers, like the one [shown below](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/potentiometers/7377726), have been around for at least 50 years.

They were used as volume controls in practically all stereo hi-fi and amplifiers until DSP and digital switch controls became cheaper to build for. That also got rid of the track noise in the pots' as they aged.

They're just two potentiometers stacked together with a single adjustment rod going through them all. Accordingly, there will be difference in each resistor's set value due to resistance tolerances and mechanical tolerances. That has to be considered for the application.

Parts with more than two gangs can also be found, though not much beyond three.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want an adjustable gain differential amplifier. An instrumentation amplifier (available as one IC or built up from separate op-amps) will do this with only one potentiometer.